# How to make Tkinter Entry field visible on button press

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a simple Log In Menu using Python Tkinter. The code works for logging in and all that stuff but I want to make a working create new account button or something like that. I will be doing that using lists but first I need to make sure that the Entry field pops up on clicking the create new account button, Here is the code :-

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox



class Login:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("Login")
        self.root.geometry("1199x600+100+50")
        
        self.bg=PhotoImage(file="png.png")
        self.bg_image=Label(self.root,image=self.bg).place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
        
        
        #Frame
        Frame_login=Frame(self.root,bg="white")
        Frame_login.place(x=150,y=150,height=340,width=500)
        
        title=Label(Frame_login,text="Login Here",font=("Impact",35, "bold","underline"),fg="red",bg="white").place(x=160,y=30)
        desc=Label(Frame_login,text="Login Area",font=("Goudy old",15, "bold","underline"),fg="purple",bg="white").place(x=80,y=100)
        lbl_user=Label(Frame_login,text="Username:",font=("Goudy old",15,"underline","bold"),fg="#00ffff",bg="white").place(x=115,y=140)
        self.txt_user=Entry(Frame_login,font=("times new roman", 15),bg="lightgray")
        self.txt_user.place(x=115,y=170,width=350,height=35)
        
        lbl_pass=Label(Frame_login,text="Password:",font=("Goudy old",15,"underline","bold"),fg="#00ffff",bg="white").place(x=115,y=210)
        self.txt_pass=Entry(Frame_login,font=("times new roman", 15),bg="lightgray")
        self.txt_pass.place(x=115,y=240,width=350,height=35)
        
        forget_btn= Button(Frame_login,command=self.register,text="Create New Account",cursor="hand2", bg="white", fg='lime', bd=0,font=("times new roman", 12)).place(x=115,y=280)
        log_btn= Button(self.root,command=self.login_function,text="Login",cursor="hand2", fg="#d77337", bg="#d77337", font=("times new roman", 20)).place(x=315,y=470,width=180,height=40)
        
        
        
        
    def login_function(self):
          if self.txt_pass.get()=="" or self.txt_user.get()=="":
              messagebox.showerror("Error!","All fields are required", parent=self.root)
          elif self.txt_user.get()!="abcd" or self.txt_pass.get()!="1234":
              messagebox.showerror("Error!"," Invalid Username or Password", parent=self.root)
          else:
              messagebox.showinfo("Welcome!","Succesfully Logged In!")
    
    
        
            

root=Tk()
obj=Login(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: assign the button to a command that will pack the entry widget but in Your case You would need a whole new frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how that might look like:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label


class Login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # data frame
        self.data_frame = Frame(self)
        self.data_frame.pack(pady=10)

        # username:
        Label(self.data_frame, text='Username:').pack()
        # username entry
        self.username = Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.username.pack()

        # password:
        Label(self.data_frame, text='Password:').pack()
        # password entry
        self.password = Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.password.pack()

        # button frame
        self.btn_frame = Frame(self)
        self.btn_frame.pack()

        # login btn
        Button(self.btn_frame, text='Login', command=self.login).pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)

        # signup button
        Button(self.btn_frame, text='Sign Up', command=self.sign_up).pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)

    def login(self):
        print('login successful')
        root.destroy()

    def sign_up(self):
        SignUp(root).pack()
        self.destroy()


class SignUp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # data frame
        self.data_frame = Frame(self)
        self.data_frame.pack(pady=10)

        # username:
        Label(self.data_frame, text='Username:').pack()
        # username entry
        self.username = Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.username.pack()

        # password:
        Label(self.data_frame, text='Password:').pack()
        # password entry
        self.password = Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.password.pack()

        # button frame
        self.btn_frame = Frame(self)
        self.btn_frame.pack()

        # login btn
        Button(self.btn_frame, text='Sign Up', command=self.sign_up).pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)

        # signup button
        Button(self.btn_frame, text='Cancel', command=self.cancel).pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)

    def sign_up(self):
        print('Signed up')
        Login(root).pack()
        self.destroy()

    def cancel(self):
        Login(root).pack()
        self.destroy()


root = Tk()
Login(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Both classes are pretty much frames and can be changed depending on which button user presses, can also add more functionality to the methods. Otherwise both classes are pretty much identical, they are almost copies just a few things like button names and method names are changed the rest is the same